# Hard forking a blockchain to new codebase?

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, blockchain-fork, project-fork

Several years ago, I forked Litecoin as a hobby project just to get some experience working with crypto code.  I generated a new genesis block and mined some for fun

I never really messed with it since then but I am still curious to learn more.  I want to change my project from Scrypt to something else like Lyra2REv2.  Monacoin for example is a litecoin fork that changed to this algo

I am not sure what all I would need to do to get a fork of Monacoin for example to sync up with my existing blockchain.  I know there are genesis block hash info in src/chainparams.cpp and block checkpoint hashes but not sure what else would need to be changed